# Check if a timestamp is not between two time periods in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table look like below

```
timestamp   start_hour1   end_hour1    start_hour2    end_hour2
```

How do I check if the timestamp is not between (start_hour1 and end_hour1) and (start_hour2 and end_hour2). start_hour2 and end_hour2 could be null as well.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What's the expected result if start_hour2 and end_hour2 could are null? A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: What version of Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the containment operators `@>` and `<@` with a `tsrange`, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  tsrange(start_hour1,end_hour1) @> timestamp AND
  tsrange(start_hour2,end_hour2) @> timestamp
FROM t
```

.. or just pure and simple `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT 
  (timestamp BETWEEN start_hour1 AND end_hour1) AND
  (timestamp BETWEEN start_hour2 AND end_hour2)
FROM t
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7d7b579a103a14e5d9bc286815bb7c61)

Comment: What do you imagine this will return if start_hour2 and end_hour2 are null?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' well, than it will return `false` :-D The OP did not specify what to do in case of `null`, just that they might occur. But yes, you've me a good point. The OP might wanna take a look at `coalesce` if he wants something else

Comment: Also the OP was looking to test whether a `timestamp` was **not** between the values.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver aha, doesn't it return `false` if they don't overlap? :-D

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I agree that the word "check" in this question is somewhat vague and it leaves room for misinterpretation. Anyway, with this logic the OP can test if the intervals do overlap with the timestamp column. Thanks for the review! +1

Comment: *"well, than it will return false :-D "* No, it won't.

Comment: As @JimJones indicates your best option seem to be either `between` or `tsrange`. However they will produce different results when nulls form all or part of the range.
Using null in tsrange [causes the range to be unbounded](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT) thus containment on tsrange(null,null) always returns true except when the timestamp tested also is null. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dd5eda96cf0af9f55c7d75e2f4653003).  So again what should be done with nulls in start_time2 and/or end_time2.